# Best way to make a simple GUI for displaying real-time data

Tags: python, user-interface

I am currently running a python script on spyder and receiving real-time data from a data source. I would like to display some of the results to a GUI and also have the function for other users to easily adjust some of the parameters in my script using that GUI. What are some of easy ways to do this?

Should I export the results to a txt file in real-time and then use another program to display them into UI?

Comment: If you plan to have the other users run the script locally on their computer, I suggest you check the functionalities offered by Tkinter.

Comment: Thanks. How about if other users will just run on my personal computer only?

Comment: Well in this case Tkinter seems like a viable option.